# change an absolutely positioned webpage into a centered one

Tags: html, css, center, absolute

So I have this template design that is currently absolutely positioned, but I'm trying to make it centered in any widescreen browser. I've tried making the width auto on the left and right side in my container, but it is still aligned with the left side.

---

Css

```
  .JosephSettin_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   width:216px; 
   height:40px;
   background: url("JosephSettin.png") no-repeat;
  }
  .home_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:472px;
   top:16px;
   width:48px; 
   height:16px;
  }
  .discography_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:528px;
   top:16px;
   width:80px; 
   height:24px;
  }
  .purchase_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:608px;
   top:16px;
   width:88px; 
   height:24px;
  }
  .about_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:696px;
   top:16px;
   width:48px; 
   height:24px;
  }
  .contact_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:744px;
   top:16px;
   width:56px; 
   height:24px;
  }
  .main__pic_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:56px;
   width:264px; 
   height:264px;
   background: url("main_pic.png") no-repeat;
  }
  .footer__lines_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:512px;
   width:800px; 
   height:24px;
   background: url("footer_lines.png") no-repeat;
  }
  .info__heading_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:32px;
   top:360px;
   width:216px; 
   height:32px;
   background: url("info_heading.png") no-repeat;
  }
  .info__pic3_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:265px;
   top:360px;
   width:159px; 
   height:112px;
   background: url("info_pic3.png") no-repeat;
  }
  .info__pic2_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:432px;
   top:360px;
   width:176px; 
   height:112px;
   background: url("info_pic2.png") no-repeat;
  }
  .info__pic1_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:616px;
   top:360px;
   width:177px; 
   height:112px;
   background: url("info_pic1.png") no-repeat;
  }
  .info__pane_png
  {
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:345px;
   width:800px; 
   height:144px;
   background: url("info_pane.png") no-repeat;
  }
  body
  {
   text-align: center;
   background-color:maroon;
  }
  #wrapper {
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
            text-align: left;
  }
  #a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color:white;
   font-weight:bold;
  }
 .style1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

html

```
    <body>
  <center>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="JosephSettin_png"> </div>
    <div class="home_png"> <a href="home.html" style="color:yellow">Home</a></div>
    <div class="discography_png"> <a href="discography.html">Discography</a></div>
    <div class="purchase_png"><a href="store.html"><span class="style1">Store</span></a></div>
    <div class="about_png"><a href="about.html">About</a></div>
    <div class="contact_png"><a href="contact.html"><span class="style1"></span>Contact</a></div>
    <div class="ad_png"> </div>
    <div class="main__pic_png"> </div>
    <div class="welcome__header_png"> </div>
    <div class="welcome__text_png"> </div>
    <div class="footer__lines_png"> </div>
    <div class="footer__text_png"> </div>
    <div class="info__pane_png"></div>
    <div class="info__heading_png"> </div>
    <div class="info__text_png"> </div>
    <div class="info__pic3_png"> </div>
    <div class="info__pic2_png"> </div>
    <div class="info__pic1_png"> </div>
    <div class="info__pic3_png"> </div>
  </div>
  </center>
  </body>
```

I know the container I create works if all my div classes aren't absolutely positioned. Do I have to change the position or did I make another error?

Comment: The css part it not very readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the `.wrapper` definition.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position

An absolutely positioned item must be inside of a relatively positioned item, or it will not display as you intended.

Comment: You should also remove the `<center>` tag, as it is deprecated, has been for some time, and serves no purpose here.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the addition. I'd forgotten the OP had that tag in there. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your wrapper needs to be position:relative; and margin:0 auto; will center the wrapper. also you can get rid of you  HTML element its not needed.

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;
width: 800px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I strongly suggest using a CSS framework like "Blueprint CSS". It'll save you a lot of time and helps not just with positioning of elements but comes with a lot of nice features like typography, css reset for multi-browser support, etc.

Comment: When you have something implemented already and want to make a minor tweak to it; throwing everything out and starting again with a framework is rarely the right thing to do.

Comment: That's not exactly true. I have converted several projects to Blueprint CSS and it was a fairly easy process. You don't have to redo ALL CSS, just major partitioning, specially easy for the author of this topic since he has everything <div>'ed already.

Comment: While it may be worth the time (depending on the site) it is hardly an answer to the question at hand, and does not help anyone learn to debug their CSS in custom situations (a skill that remains useful no matter what frameworks you use).